# How to adapt the comments of any post in a recycleView?

Tags: android

Hello My idea is to get all the comments of each post from my social network like Facebook or instragram.

My code is just showing me the comments which belongs to a post in each post
i'm getting two lists one of this is for post and the second one is for comments.

These are my Entity classes

```
package com.example.fuegosantoapp.entidades;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Comentarios implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private String comentario;
    private String hora;
    private String fecha;
    private String email;
    private String avatar;
```

```
package com.example.fuegosantoapp.entidades;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Publicacion implements Serializable {

    private String id_publicaciones;
    private String publicaciones;
    private String descripcion;
    private String cover;
    private String fecha_publicacion;
    private String autor;
    private String ftitulo;
    private String comentario;
    private String hora;
    private String fecha;
    private String email;
    private String avatar;
```

and I'm running my list like so

```
Publicacion publicacion = null;
        Comentarios comentarios = null;

        JSONArray json = response.optJSONArray("publicacion");
        JSONArray json2 = response.optJSONArray("comments");
        Integer id_publicacion = null;
        Integer id_publicacion_comentarios = null;
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Maria: " + json2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                publicacion = new Publicacion();
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(i);
                //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Publicacion: " + jsonObject.optInt("id"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ;
                //id_publicacion = 1;
                id_publicacion = jsonObject.optInt("id");
                //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Publicacion: " + id_publicacion, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                publicacion.setId_publicaciones(jsonObject.optString("id"));
                publicacion.setFtitulo(jsonObject.optString("titulo"));
                publicacion.setDescripcion(jsonObject.optString("descripcion"));
                publicacion.setCover((jsonObject.optString("cover")));
                publicacion.setPublicaciones(jsonObject.optString("publicacion"));
                publicacion.setFecha_publicacion(jsonObject.optString("fecha_publicacion"));
                publicacion.setAutor(jsonObject.optString("autor"));



                for (int j = 0; j < json2.length(); j++) {
                    comentarios = new Comentarios();
                    JSONObject jsonObject2 = null;
                    jsonObject2 = json2.getJSONObject(j);
                    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Length Comentario: " + json2.length(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    id_publicacion_comentarios = jsonObject2.optInt("publicacion_id");


                    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Publicacion en Comentario: " +id_publicacion_comentarios, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                       if (id_publicacion == id_publicacion_comentarios) {

                           comentarios.setId(jsonObject2.optInt("publicacion_id"));
                           comentarios.setComentario(jsonObject2.optString("comentario"));
                           comentarios.setEmail(jsonObject2.optString("email"));
                           comentarios.setAvatar(jsonObject2.optString("avatar"));
                           comentarios.setHora(jsonObject2.optString("hora"));
                           comentarios.setFecha(jsonObject2.optString("fecha"));

                             Log.i("id", String.valueOf(id_publicacion));
                             Log.i("id_publication", String.valueOf(id_publicacion_comentarios));
                              listaComentarios.add(comentarios);
                              Log.i("Comments", comentarios.getComentario());
                       }
                       //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Comentario: " + jsonObject.optString("comentario"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                Log.i("publications", publicacion.getId_publicaciones());
                listaPublicaciones.add(publicacion);
            }
```

How can  i do it ?